# What is the best practice when it comes to creating hibernate sessions in multi-threaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, session

Currently, for my project, i am creating session for every database related query and close it immediately.

```
public Address address(Contact contact) {
    Address result = null;
    Session session=factory.openSession();
    try{
        result = contact.getAddress();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

in a single thread of execution for a web page, there are numerous calls similar to the above within java code and JSP code.

In addition, i have a java task in a thread of its own executing calls that require open a session and closing it within the same thread.

For some reason, occasionally i get a session timeout with only one user logged in my application and 10 threads running in the background.

Question is... should i create a session in a filter before executing the entire page and call factory.getCurrentSession() in all database related methods? Will this be thread safe if i close the session in the filter after request is processed in the filter? Will this approach make the application scalable and prevents session timeouts?

Answer (score 0):

I can't promise it will solve your session timeouts as you don't actually have a root cause (I would trigger a timeout and then perform a thread dump to debug further).

However, I have managed sessions in filters in several projects with great success and performance.  This is a common approach known as [session-per-request](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch02.html#session-per-request).  I have not used `factory.getCurrentSession()` myself as I use JPA and just created a `ThreadLocal` to store the `EntityManager` (e.g. Session) so I managed that myself.  The link above references `factory.getCurrentSession()` so it should work provided you use it correctly.

Should you need to take performance even further you can put in some mechanism to determine, in your filter, if your request needs to access the database or not (if all your requests access the database this would be pointless) and if they don't need to access the database don't create the session.  However, if I recall, sessions are pretty effectively lazily initialized when you first use them so the performance hit from creating an unused session should be quite small.

Comment: Thanks.. the snippet i put in is for lazy loading of associated objects as i have declared them to be lazy in *.hbm.xml files.. This a great help from you... i start changing my code.. hopefully i am not going to face thread safety issues...

Comment: I tried adding <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property> in config file and tried using factory.getCurrectSession().. but when i try to access web page, server is returning a blank html file... anybody has ideas why this is happening?

Comment: finally i made it work... added <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>  and used factory.getCurrectSession().  Did not add anything else.. and it is working as i expected.. Thanks..